# What can a lawyer do to make the government formulate better policies for tech startups?

Tags: business, tax-law

In Nigeria, most policies by the government affecting businesses are antagonistic to the growth of businesses partly due to lack of knowledge on the path of the government about the country's and world's changing economic climate and also corruption.

There are incessant taxes such as radio tax that a fledgling startup would have to pay to the government. These taxes are not only bad for these businesses but also hampers the country's development.

So as a lawyer, what can be done to the government and a startup to ensure these startups are not strangulated out of business?

Comment: In general, changing the law is political, and as long as the law is in place you have to deal with it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about political processes, not the law or legal process.

Comment: I'm interpreting the question not so much as one about lobbying the government to foster a more friendly business climate, but rather about bringing affirmative litigation or using other legal mechanisms to protect a business from dangerous regulations. If that's the case, it seems the question should remain open.

Comment: bdb484, that's exactly what I meant. What are the legal methods by which a lawyer can prevent the existence of such policies. So, that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much, other than run for office and change the law. The [constitution](http://www.nigeria-law.org/ConstitutionOfTheFederalRepublicOfNigeria.htm#Powers_of_Federal_Republic_of_Nigeria) grants broad legislative powers to the National Assembly. In the US, one would sue the government for exceeding its authority in passing some law, but because of the Commerce Clause and the Tax and Spending clauses of the Constitution, such a lawsuit against federal authority to impose a tax is unlikely to succeed (here). However, it is always possible that a particular tax is not being imposed according to law, so you could consult [this source](http://www.lawnigeria.com/Laws/Laws-Taxation-Regime.php) to at least get names of tax-related acts (it's not an entirely safe website). For instance, a suit was filed over the (Lagos State) Motor Vehicle Radio license fee.